# Mongoose js validation on sub object multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am attempting to validate an entire object (multipel fields) within mongoose.

I have the following custom schema definition:

```
module.exports.ItemQuantityPair = (ItemModel, strictStacking)=>{
  return {
    type: {
      itemID: { type:Number, required:true },
      quantity: { type:Number, min:1, default:1 },
    },
    validate: {
        validator: async value => { //stacking
          if(!strictStacking || value.quantity===1) //if no strict stacking, or only quantity of 1 don't validate
           return true;
          let item = await ItemModel.findOne({itemID:value.itemID}); //otherwise get the item and check if its stackable
          if(!item.stackable)
            return false; //invalid, quantity > 1 and not stackable
          else
            return true; //valid, quantity > 1 and stackable
        },
        message: props=>`${props.value} this item was supplied with a quantity larger than 1, but the item was found to not be stackable. Ensure only stackable items have quantity > 1`
    }, 
  }
}
```

Then later in my schema I use this custom object like so:

```
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
inventory: [ItemQuantityPair(ItemModel, true)] //inventory is a list of ItemQuantity pairs
});
```

When I try this, I'm presented with the error `TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: 'undefined' is not a valid type within the array 'inventory'` I assume this is because I can't assign an object tp the `type` field since these are the only built-in types: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype. Normally I would validate each field separately, but this specific validation requires both fields' values (quantity and itemID) to be determined as valid or not.

How can I cleanly accomplish validation on multiple fields?

Thanks